# Changing the stroke width of text in Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to create a custom View where I draw a text with a custom font and want to control the stroke width. I've overridden the `onDraw` method to look like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Typeface mGothamFont =
                Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/gotham_thin.ttf");

        Paint mTextLargePaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextLargePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D0CFCF"));
        mTextLargePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mTextLargePaint.setStrokeWidth(1.2f);
        mTextLargePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextLargePaint.setTextSize(65);
        mTextLargePaint.setTypeface(mGothamFont);
        canvas.drawText("Bla Bla", (getWidth() - mTextLargePaint.measureText("Bla Bla")) / 2.0f, 100, mTextLargePaint);
    }
```

(Ignore the fact that I'm creating a `Paint` in the `onDraw` method, this is just for the example).
But no matter what I set as the parameter of setStrokeWidth, the text is really really thin. I've tried commenting the `setTypeface` line so that I used the regular system font, but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: for e text size == 65 you want to use a stroke with width == 1.2 ???

Comment: It's just for the example... I tried lots of other values (calculated from dp), but it doesn't seem to change how the text looks.

Comment: tried without custom typeface? tried with different mTextLargePaint.setStyle() ?

Comment: Yes, stroke, fill, stroke and fill - they all had the same effect.

Comment: no, they don't have the same effect... otherwise, what would they be for?

Comment: OK but that is exactly my problem, they all had the same effect - which is none. They do affect if you draw a circle for example.

Comment: no, try this: http://pastebin.com/FBG5LSqt

Comment: Actually Yes. After porting it back to my code, I realized that the problem was only apparent in Android Studio, not at run-time. Thanks!